# Trying to catch divide by zero and non integer submissions in a VB Windows Form, What to do?

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms, zero, divide

I'm trying to divide two numbers by each other but also not letting the user enter a divide by zero or entering letters and anything other then integers. As of right now I am trying to get the divide by zero with:

```
Public Class Form2
Dim answer As Double
Private Sub btnDiv_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDiv.Click
    Dim num1 As Double
    Dim num2 As Double
    txtOne.Text = num1
    txtTwo.Text = num2
    If num2 = "0" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Divide by Zero. Enter Another Integer.")
    Else
        lblDiv.Text = num1 / num2
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Anyone know how I should go around doing this or if I am at least on the right track

Comment: you had swapped it. write `num1 = txtOne.Text` instead. Do it also in txtTwo.Text

Comment: Please be mindful of comparing a `String` and a `Double`. Notice `num2 = "0"`. `num2` is a `Double`, `"0"` is a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim answer As Double

    Private Sub btnDiv_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDiv.Click
        Dim num1 As Double = Double.Parse(txtOne.Text)
        Dim num2 As Double = Double.Parse(txtTwo.Text)

        Try    
            answer = num1 / num2
            lblDiv = answer.ToString()
        Catch Ex As DivideByZeroException
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by zero. Enter another number.")
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

or

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim answer As Double

    Private Sub btnDiv_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDiv.Click
        Dim num1 As Double = Double.Parse(txtOne.Text)
        Dim num2 As Double = Double.Parse(txtTwo.Text)

        If num2 = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by zero. Enter another number.")
        Else  
            answer = num1 / num2
            lblDiv = answer.ToString()               
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

One important thing I saw in your original code: **be consistent with your use of types!** You create the **Double** values `num1` and `num2`, but try to assign to them direct from a **String** and try to compare `num2` with a **String** `"0"` while the error message calls them all **Integers.** *There are so many many ways to make a string that will parse to 0!*

The user will give you strings from the keyboard. Get from there to the precise type you need as quickly as possible, and stay there as long as possible until you need to show a string to the user again.

Comment: Will division of `Double` values ever result in a `DivideByZeroException`?  My limited tests in VB.Net seems to indicate that the result will be `Infinity` or `-Infinity`  If the types were `Integer` or `Decimal` then a `DivideByZeroException` would result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`Try Catch Exception` for this instead of if else statement.

Comment: As what they always said, _prevention is better than cure_. So preventing an exception to happen is always better than letting it throw an exception then catch it.

Comment: @CrushSundae meh. You can't push the button fast enough to make this have a measurable impact on performance of this code. Go with what you feel is more expressive and precise in this case.

Comment: @CrushSundae for me it is the best method if you just want to catch the dividedbyzero exception, if you have multiple conditions then if-else statement will be better.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Thank you, I'm enlightened. :) But will stick to my point.